# BIND values from Documents to a SPARQL Variable (MarkLogic)

Tags: sparql, bind, marklogic

I am currently trying to see if it's possible to extract a certain value from a document and bind it to a variable in SPARQL

For example if i have such a document in MarkLogic.

/person/John

```
<person_data>
   <name>John</name>
   <age>25</age>
</person_data>
```

using this data I attempted various ways to bind it such as using XPath in sem:sparql as shown below

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";

sem:sparql('
PREFIX fn : <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions>
SELECT *
WHERE {
?s ?p ?o .
BIND (fn:doc("/person/John")//name/text() AS ?name)
}
',
(),
(),
()
)
```

However, this resulted in an error. Hence, I greatly appreciate any advise given on accomplishing this.

Comment: What was the error message that resulted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SPARQL engine has no access to documents, but there is a better solution anyhow. You can use [Template Driven Extraction](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE) for this. It can expose an SQL view on documents, but also ['Identify Triples in Documents'](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/semantics/tde#chapter). It effectively means that particular values can be projected into the triple index, and will become accessible as RDF data like any other RDF data in your database.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, I would like to ask whether time complexity or space complexity will be affected? Is it better to just create another subject, pred, triple document or projecting my values this way will be more effective? @grtjn

Comment: I would also like to ask if it is possible to embed a TDE with other values? Such as embedding <age>25<age> into the TDE for instance.

Comment: I'm fond of using TDE. It allows me to gather info in human-readable xml or json, and use TDE to put SQL and SPARQL lenses onto it. TDE generated triples are equally performant as other triples in MarkLogic, but save you from the trouble of embedding sem:triple structures inline, which only adds to disk space. TDE allows for so-called variable, and xpath expressions with hard-coded values. It does not allow accessing other documents though. It runs at indexing time (part of commit), and only has current document within scope.

Comment: If TDE only has current document within it's scope is the URI of a document within TDE's scope? If yes, how do i access the URI to use as my subject? @grtjn