# Multiple Templates for the same path (MarkLogic)

Tags: marklogic

Carried over from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55162838/bind-values-from-documents-to-a-sparql-variable-marklogic/55167215?noredirect=1#comment97095193_55167215) where Template Driven Extraction(TDE) was mentioned as a way to retrieve values from a certain element.

Currently, I am attempting to create multiple TDE templates at once for a certain path. The code I used to to accomplish this is written below

```
xquery version "1.0-ml"; 
import module namespace tde = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde" 
  at "/MarkLogic/tde.xqy";

let $t1 :=
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
  <context>/question</context>
    <vars>
      <var>
        <name>EX</name>
        <val>""</val>
      </var>
    </vars>
  <triples>
    <triple>
      <subject>
        <val>sem:iri( $EX || name)</val>
      </subject>
      <predicate>
        <val>sem:iri("/has_tags")</val>
      </predicate>
      <object>
        <val>xs:dateTime( $EX || tags)</val>
      </object>
    </triple>
  </triples>
  </template>

let $t2 :=
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
  <context>/question</context>
    <vars>
      <var>
        <name>EX</name>
        <val>""</val>
      </var>
    </vars>
  <triples>
    <triple>
      <subject>
        <val>sem:iri( $EX || name)</val>
      </subject>
      <predicate>
        <val>sem:iri("/date_posted")</val>
      </predicate>
      <object>
        <val>xs:dateTime( $EX || date_posted)</val>
      </object>
    </triple>
  </triples>
  </template>

return(
tde:template-insert("question_has_tags.xml",$t1, (), "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde"),
tde:template-insert("question_date_posted.xml",$t2, (), "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde")
)
```

A sample document

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<question>
<tags>uifontweighttrait,spark-thriftserver,alarmmanager,recursive-type,string-iteration,security-trimming,google-earth</tags>
<date_posted>1978-06-23T22:22:43</date_posted>
<name>/question_on_forum</name>
</question>
```

The template was tested using

```
tde:node-data-extract(fn:doc("/question"));
```

Which resulted in the error

```
[1.0-ml] TDE-EVALFAILED: tde:node-data-extract(fn:doc("/question/780989102826685")) -- Eval for Object='xs:dateTime( $EX || tags)' returns TDE-BADVALEXPRESSION: Invalid val expression: XDMP-CAST: (err:FORG0001) Invalid cast: "spotify,databags,laravel-horizon" cast as xs:dateTime
```

This error was solved the moment I removed one of the template

===========UPDATE===========

The codes below were used in an attempt to create multiple triples per template. However, it also results in the same error

```
xquery version "1.0-ml"; 
import module namespace tde = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde" 
  at "/MarkLogic/tde.xqy";

let $t2 :=
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
  <context>/question</context>
  <triples>
    <triple>
      <subject>
        <val>sem:iri( uri)</val>
      </subject>
      <predicate>
        <val>sem:iri("/date_posted")</val>
      </predicate>
      <object>
        <val>xs:dateTime(date_posted)</val>
      </object>
    </triple>
  </triples>
  <triples>
    <triple>
      <subject>
        <val>sem:iri(uri)</val>
      </subject>
      <predicate>
        <val>sem:iri("/has_tags")</val>
      </predicate>
      <object>
        <val>tags</val>
      </object>
    </triple>
  </triples>
  </template>
return(
tde:template-insert("question_date_posted.xml",$t2, (), "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde")
)
```

Node Extract for testing (This is where the error will occur)

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

tde:node-data-extract(fn:doc("/question"));
```

Example Document Used

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<question>
<tags>jsondate,jmsserializerbundle,omnikey,eula,template-deduction,pyclipper,asyncpg,naming,kubeconfig,timer-trigger</tags>
<date_posted>1986-02-21T22:27:50</date_posted>
<uri>/question</uri>
</question>
```

Comment: This won't work: `xs:dateTime( $EX || tags)`, I think you just want `tags` there. And this won't work either: `xs:dateTime( $EX || date_posted)`, it would have to be `$EX || xs:dateTime(date_posted)`, but I expect you want to use `xs:dateTime(date_posted)`..

Comment: By the way, particular reason why you are using separate templates? You can create multiple triples at once, and if you need conditional triples, use sub-templates with sub-context on the optional element..

Comment: Sorry I did this post while I was away from the actual codes, so I copied and pasted some portion without managing to edit everything properly. In any case, I have thought of creating multiple triples at once in a single template but it does not work as expected. I have edited the post to show what i attempted. @grtjn

Comment: Your update shows partial code, maybe the error is of the other code? The double `<triples>` element looks a bit overkill, but doesn't seem to throw a validate error.

Comment: Yes it actually goes through when adding to the schema and validating it shows "true" but the error is thrown upon execution of node-data-extract. Ill update with the neccessary code and data used so you maybe able to replicate it. @grtjn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found out the issue. It was a minor mistake on my part. The error is pointed out by a comment.

```
let $t2 :=
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
  <context>/question</context>
  <triples>
    <triple>
      <subject>
        <val>sem:iri( uri)</val>
      </subject>
      <predicate>
        <val>sem:iri("/date_posted")</val>
      </predicate>
      <object>
        <val>xs:dateTime(date_posted)</val>
      </object>
    </triple>
  </triples>
  <triples>
    <triple>
      <subject>
        <val>sem:iri(uri)</val>
      </subject>
      <predicate>
        <val>sem:iri("/has_tags")</val>
      </predicate>
      <object>
        <val>xs:string(tags)</val>     #needed to determine the variable type of tags object
      </object>
    </triple>
  </triples>
  </template>
```